# Does Alagaësia have a moon?

Tags: inheritance-cycle, worldbuilding

I remember that their sun is called Aiedail, but I can't remember if they have (visually) a moon.

They must have some kind of moon because when Roran and Clovis talk about getting the villagers, near Narda, they talk about the tides. However it might be an error, because I've recently realised that Alagaësia is a disaster worldbuilding-wise. I mean, a desert touching a forest? It doesn't compute climatically speaking.

Comment: As I recall, the desert may have been formed through an unnatural process. And sometimes deserts and forests can be [closer than you think](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yatir_Forest).

Comment: > I mean, a desert touching a forest? It doesn't compute climatically speaking. - Keep in mind that in-universe, Du Weldenvarden was largely formed by the elves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's definitely a moon.  Just grabbing my copy of *Inheritance* (I don't have e-books of the first 3) I can find:

> Darkness lay all around them, heavy and oppressive. A thick layer
> of clouds obscured **the moon** and the stars. Without the red werelight
> Angela held in the palm of her hand, even Eragon and the elves
> would have been unable to see.
>
> <sub>*Inheritance*, Under Hill and Stone</sub>

and

> They flew on in silence as **the waxing three-quarter moon** rose above
> the jagged peaks of the Spine. By its light, the land looked as if it
> were made out of pewter, and Eragon amused himself by imagining
> that it was an immense sculpture the dwarves had carved and stored
> within a cave as large as Alagaësia itself.
>
> <sub>*Inheritance*, On the Wings of a Dragon</sub>

So they don't just have a moon, it's likely comparable in size to Earth's moon in order to cast a similar level of brightness.

Note that Aiedail isn't the sun, it's "the morning star," probably the equivalent of Venus.

> Now, however, **the morning star, Aiedail,** had risen in the east—
> heralding the arrival of dawn’s first light—and the time had come to
> ready themselves for battle.

Comment: There's also that bit where they end up flying high enough to see the world's curvature and Eragon speculates whether it would be possible to fly to the moon.